# get html value from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get the value of the $category[$category] from jquery

this is my html

```html
<select name='category' id='category'>
                        <option value='0'>Please select</option>
                        <?php 
                        $param = array();
                        $categories = $core -> getProductsCategories($param);
                        if($categories) {
                            foreach($categories as $category) {
                        print "<option value='$category[id]'>$category[category]</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add to sales order" />          
            <div class="messages"></div>
```

this is my jquery i want to get the value of the array

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(function() {
  //var toAdd = $("select[name=category]").val();
        var toAddd = $('select[name="category"]').val();
    //  $('#messages1').append("<p>"+toAdd+"</p>");
        $('.messages').append("<p>"+toAddd+"</p>");
      
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you referring to all the `<option>` values populated by your PHP script? And display all of those into a JS Array?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this demo

```js
$(function() {
  var ctg = $('#category');
  $('#add').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Selected category value', ctg.val());
    console.log('Selected category text', ctg.find(':selected').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='category' id='category'>
  <option value='0'>Please select</option>
  <option value='1'>Category 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Category 2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add to sales order" />
<br/>Open console ...
```